# Making apps think you have a lower version of android

Tags: applications, downgrade

so i want an app or something like that that makes apps think you have a lower version of android even thogh your android version does not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by rooting and installing build.prop editor app from there can change model no. of phone, version, manufacturer name and many more stuff yeah you can also simply revert it.